# Trying to make UITableViewAutomaticDimension work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have to solve some problems in existing project (Objective-C, Xcode 7.3, iOS).

Here I have a Table View in which I need to have some resizable cells to fit the content. The cells include Labels. The project uses `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` but it doesn't seem to work properly. The text in the cell goes beyond the right border.

So now i've checked some points:

1. The "Lines" property of the cell in Attributes Inspector is set to 0.
2. I have 4 constraints for the Label (pic related).
3. The `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method contains only `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`.

Here is the code, where `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

[Constraints screenshot <======](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UIoq.png)

Comment: Can you show me the cell constraint?

Comment: @Bhadresh Mulsaniya I've added the picture, sorry

Comment: I have seen it later after your question update!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 186, 0)]; //max width that is allowed for label
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    int GAP = 3;
    float height = 0;
    float fontSize = 14;
    NSString *cellText = yourtext;
    lbl.font= [ UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME_Ubuntu size: fontSize];
    bl.text = cellText;
    [lbl sizeToFit];
    height += lbl.frame.size.height;
    height += GAP;

    return height;
  }
```

Or try below one

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        /*
        for dynamic cell heigh according to the description display in cell
         */

        NSDictionary *dict1 = (NSDictionary*)[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *cellText = [dict1 valueForKey:@"test"];
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME_GOTHAM_4 size:11.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];


            return labelSize.height + 80;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need set in IB or in code

```
[yourLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
[yourLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

And after set the text call this

```
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Hope this help. I took this from Self Sizing example from Apple